# material-ui menu width and cdk-overlay-pane customization

Tags: html, css, angular-material, overlay, angular-cdk

I am using mat-menu from Material-UI to have a menu. I want the menu to take all the width of the button which make it appear.

When I don't custom the width I got this:

[image: Width no modified]

However, when I modify in the inspector to add the propriety `width: 100%` to the class `cdk-overlay-pane`. I got this :

[image: With modified in the inspector]

But when I click elsewhere in the page and click again in the mat-menu. It shows the mat-menu at top left corner of the page.

Also, when I modify the class `cdk-overlay-pane` directly in the code. The menu is showing directly at top left corner of the page.

My question is: How to modify the mat-menu width to show with the result of the second picture and have a persistent result knowing that the structure is like that when we add a `mat-menu` in the HTML

[image: Html structure]

Comment: Can you paste your code ? The last image is not really visible